# Linux Mint 19 Terminal refuses to add repository despite giving correct source for R3.5 installation files

Tags: r, installation, repository, linux-mint

I have to install the latest version of R on my Linux Mint 19 computer in order to run some bioinformatics tools (Biostrings). I then followed [this website](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04/) for the tutorial (I suppose things are not very different with Mint or Ubuntu after all). However, after I typed in the third command line into the Terminal, which is

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

it replied

> Malformed input, repository not added.

Now I understood that there is a typo in the command on the website, and I myself corrected it to

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran35/'
```

However, the problem still exists.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: There isn't a typo. There should be a space after "ubuntu" as in your first example.

Comment: It looks like the same issue is discussed here:  https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=290679. The suggestion to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually looks promising to me (but might require some fluency with terminal editors like nano or vim)

Comment: Yes, I would also suggest manually adding the entry to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or a custom file for example `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cran.list`.

Comment: Thanks guy, I've tried to manually edited the sources.list file but the result was still negative. (still don't know how the guy iin the Linux Mint post was able to solve his problem).

Comment: I ran into the same problem while following [Install Docker in Linux Mint 19.1](https://www.unixtutorial.org/install-docker-in-linux-mint-19-1) on Linux Mint 19.2 and the manual edit solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
```

then add the following line

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

then,

```
sudo apt update
```